# PowerPoint Visual Basic NO refrescan gráficos

Tags: vba

Estoy intentando mediante una macro de vba cambiar en un gráfico de powerpoint.
Lo que me está ocurriendo es que cuando cambio los ejes mediante PlotBy no se refresca el gráfico hasta que me meto en los datos
Hay alguna forma mediante vb en **powerpoint** para poder refrescar los gráficos sin tener que meterme dentro?
Un saludo y gracias
M

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buenas por ejemplo, pongo:  `Pres1.Slides(numDiapo).Shapes("Grafico").Chart.PlotBy = xlColumns`   y no se actualiza, he de meterme en el gráfico con el ratón y entonces lo hace.